# Using "raster.transform" function of "rasterio" in Python

Tags: python, rasterio, affine-transformation

When I execute the "raster.transform" function in Python it returns me a matrix.

[image]

What I can understand is that it tells me my data has a 10 m pixel resolution,
It also tells me that my left bounding box is at 728749.5 and my top bounding box is at 4373200.5. What I don't understand is the rest of the elements like "-10", "1", and "0s". I also noticed that it can be a 2x3 matrix. Why is this dimension different?

[image]

I would like to know what does this matrix conveys and how can I use this information, especially when I have this info from two different rasters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `.transform` property returns an instance of an [Affine](https://github.com/sgillies/affine) object.
This is essentially an [augmented affine transformation matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Affine_transformation#Augmented_matrix), where the 3x3 matrix always has a bottom row [0 0 1].

```
| x' |   | a  b  c | | x |
| y' | = | d  e  f | | y |
| 1  |   | 0  0  1 | | 1 |
```

The 2x3 matrix representation only shows the six coefficients (*a*, *b*, *c*, *d*, *e*, *f*) that represent this information. These coefficients are very similar to a 6-line [world file](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/World_file), where the only difference is that a world file registers the offset to the *centre* of the origin cell, whereas GDAL (and rasterio) register the *corner* of the origin cell.

A few general remarks:

- Coefficient *a* is generally the cell width along the *x* dimension. This is only true if *b* and *d* are zero.
- Coefficient *e* is generally negative, since the *y* dimension is oriented in the opposite direction (upwards) to the raster row direction (downwards). Again, this is only true if *b* and *d* are zero.
- Coefficients *b* and *d* are usually zero, unless this is an affine transform for a rotated or sheared raster. If they are not zero, then *a* and *e* don't represent cell dimensions.
- Offsets *c* and *f* are usually to the corner of the upper-left cell.

Further reading:

- https://www.perrygeo.com/python-affine-transforms.html